# Quantity constant along geodesics.

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I’m given an open set $ U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$ and endowed with the first fundamental form
\begin{equation}
I= dr^2 + c^2 d \theta^2.
\end{equation}
Here $c$ is a smooth, nonnegative function with domain $[0, \infty)$ depending only on the radial coordinate.

I would like to show that the quantity $ c^2 (dt/t) \theta$ is contant along the geodesics.
I computed the Christoffel symbols and the geodesics equations. Hence I tried to take the covariant derivative of the vector field $(0, \sqrt{(dt/t) \theta})$, to show that it is zero. But no success. Any hint?

Thanks!